# How to save the values in diged keys of a hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash:

```
a = {b: {c: {d: e}}}
```

How can I save `d` from `a`? Should I write like:

```
x = [:b][:c]
a(x) = "foo"
```

`a`
output `{b:{c:"foo"}}`

Comment: do you want to get the keys of the any hash, if yes, then you can just do `keys = a[:b][:c].keys` if not, you need to make your question more clear about what is it that you are looking for

Comment: Are you looking for `Hash#dig` and `a.dig(:b, :c)` or `a.dig(*[:b, :c])`?

Comment: Just a note that `dig` is from Ruby 2.3. So if you're using any version lower than 2.3 then this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

As mu points out in the comments you probably want to use `dig`:

```
a = {b: {c: {d: :e}}}
keys = [:b, :c] 
d_and_e = a.dig(*keys)
```

This will return `{d: :e}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
a[:b][:c].keys.first # => :d
a[:b][:c].keys.first.to_s # => "d"
```

Answer (score -1):

hash.keys.join or hash.keys(if there is only one key)

Comment: I have no idea what this is trying to say